# Delphi losing mysql connection after some idle

Tags: mysql, delphi, firemonkey, mydac

I am using MyDac to connect MySQL and my Delphi Project, here is what is happening:

When I start the application, everything works fine but after some idle if I try to make a new search I get the error: 'Acess denied to user for routine myprocedure'

- I'm using roles to control the permissions
- I created a routine on mysql to run the select

After this, I need to restart the application

Comment: For FireDac you make sure any connection setup code is in `AfterConnect` so if the connection is lost and re-established it again gets setup the way you want. See if there is something similar for mydac.

Comment: This is probably a question to ask in DevArt forum or directly to DevArt tech support. See https://www.devart.com/mydac/ and click on "support" in the top menu.

Comment: @Brian I have a query setting a role in AfterConnect

Comment: What kind of "idle" you mentioned before? Are you sure that your connection mechanic is correct for it? Could you give some detailed information?